# deleting tables on MySQL from jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, delete-row

Problem when deleting tables from jdbc

I have a. jar that deletes records from multiple tables through a previously prepared statement

i did it this way:

```
-- SQL
delete from tabla_a using tabla_a join tabla_c join tabla_b join tabla_d
where tabla_a.tabla_c_id = tabla_c.id and tabla_c.tabla_b_id = tabla_b.id
and tabla_b.tabla_d_id = tabla_d.id and tabla_d.field = 2;
```

note: where (?) is an integer

```
// Java
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dsn, user, pass);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

does not work does not **erase any record**, I tested the SQL directly to MySQL and working properly.

Comment: Did you disable autocommit mode in the JDBC code?

Comment: I've tried it with autocommit enabled and also disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a PreparedStatement instead, and set the parameters. Something along these lines:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dsn, user, pass);
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, 2);
int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Maybe you should post the code *exactly* as it is. For instance, in the SQL snippet there's no question mark in the query, and in the Java snippet you're omitting type declarations, etc.

Comment: I forget to add a table to the query but did not work so the value passed as parameter.

Comment: Hágame caso y transcriba aquí el código *completo* de la parte relevante, de lo contrario no lo voy a poder ayudar. Y menos con ese inglés :P

Comment: si que pena con google translate, pero lo que queria decir era que ya encontre la solucion y hubo un error con el campo de where por eso no borraba